# Why does a T-SQL CROSS APPLY sometimes behave like a LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, aggregate-functions, cross-apply

Most of the documentation I have read suggests that a CROSS APPLY acts in a similar manner to an INNER JOIN whereby a row is only included in the output if there are matching rows in both source tables.

However, this doesn't always seem to be the case, for example if you run the following SQL query the results will contain 3 rows where one of them includes a number of NULLs due to there being no row in the right-hand table:

```
CREATE TABLE #Order
(
    Id          int PRIMARY KEY
)

CREATE TABLE #OrderItem
(
    OrderId     int NOT NULL,
    Price       decimal(18, 2) NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO #Order
VALUES(1), (2), (3)

INSERT INTO #OrderItem
VALUES(1, 10), (1, 20), (3,100)

SELECT *
FROM #Order o
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT SUM(Price) AS TotalPrice, COUNT(*) AS Items, MIN(Price) AS MinPrice
    FROM #OrderItem
    WHERE OrderId = o.Id
) t

DROP TABLE #Order
DROP TABLE #OrderItem
```

Does anyone know why that is?

Comment: `CROSS APPLY` will never act like a `OUTER JOIN`. If you wanted it to, you would need to use `OUTER APPLY`. Your subquery will always return a row because it only contains aggregates, and thus it always returns a row.

Comment: @Larnu but that's exactly what's not happening in op's query. It returns 3 rows, that's the question

Comment: 3 rows is correct though. 1 for each row in the table `#Order`.

Comment: I know it's correct, but for the purpose of the question, it is acting kind of like an `OUTER JOIN`

Answer (score 5):

### TL;DR;

The reason this is happening is because **the aggregate is a scalar aggregate.**

---

### There are two types of aggregates:

- **Vector aggregates**

  - Needs a `GROUP BY` clause, even by the empty set `()`
  - Returns no rows at all if the input has no rows
- **Scalar aggregates**

  - No `GROUP BY` clause
  - Always returns exactly one row, even if there are no input rows. `COUNT` returns `0`, others return `NULL`.

The one you have used is a scalar aggregate, so **there is always one row returned.**

To get a vector aggregate, **you need to add a `GROUP BY`**

```sql
SELECT *
FROM #Order o
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT SUM(oi.Price) AS TotalPrice, COUNT(*) AS Items, MIN(oi.Price) AS MinPrice
    FROM #OrderItem oi
    WHERE oi.OrderId = o.Id   -- always specify inner table in column references
    GROUP BY ()   -- the empty set
-- alternatively
    GROUP BY oi.OrderId
) t
```

---

See also this excellent article by @PaulWhite:  [Fun with Scalar and Vector Aggregates](https://www.sql.kiwi/2012/03/fun-with-aggregates.html)

Comment: Thanks Charlieface, That explains it, I had noticed that the addition of a GROUP BY reduced the resultset down to 2 rows :-)

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone know why that is?

Because the query you are APPLYing returns a row whether or not there any matching rows, since it's an aggregate query.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you think that an aggregate returns no rows when there are no applicable rows. This isn't true if there is no `GROUP BY` clause. Take the following nonsense query:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) AS C,
       SUM(object_ID) AS S,
       MAX(object_ID) AS M
FROM sys.tables
WHERE [name]= N'sdfhjklsdgfgjklb807ty3480A645*)&TY0';
```

Now, unless you have a very silly name for one of your objects, you will still get a result set with a single here:

```
C           S           M
----------- ----------- -----------
0           NULL        NULL
```

As such, for your query, you too get a row for **every** row in your sub query, because it just contains aggregates and no `GROUP BY`.

If you don't want a row for `Id` 2, then you could use a lateral subquery, or a `WHERE`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM #Order O
     JOIN (SELECT sq.OrderId,
                  SUM(sq.Price) AS TotalPrice,
                  COUNT(*) AS Items,
                  MIN(sq.Price) AS MinPrice
           FROM #OrderItem sq
           GROUP BY sq.OrderID) OI ON O.Id = OI.OrderID;

SELECT *
FROM #Order o
     CROSS APPLY(SELECT SUM(ca.Price) AS TotalPrice,
                        COUNT(*) AS Items,
                        MIN(ca.Price) AS MinPrice
                 FROM #OrderItem ca
                 WHERE ca.OrderId = o.Id) OI
WHERE OI.Items > 0;
```

Comment: Depends if you have a `GROUP BY` https://www.sql.kiwi/2012/03/fun-with-aggregates.html